# Linq: List of lists to a long list

Tags: c#, linq

I've got an object of type `A` which consists of a list of objects of type `B`:

```
class A { list<B> Alist;}
class B { string C; string D;}
```

In my program I have a list of `A` objects:

```
list<A> listOfA = computeAList();
```

and I would like to select all the `C` strings in that list. The following statement I hoped would give me the result I wanted; it returns a list of lists containing the `C`'s:

```
var query = from objectA in listOfA
            select objectA.Alist.FindAll(x => x.C.Length > 0).C;
```

Is there a way to get a single list of all the `C`'s instead?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

ybo's answer would have been my first response too. The query expression equivalent of this is:

```
var query = from a in computeAList()
            from b in a.Alist
            select b.C;
```

For the sake of completeness, the other answers in this thread are variations on the same theme.

From ybo (the exact same query, expressed as dot notation):

```
var query = listOfA.SelectMany(a => a.Alist, (a, b) => b.C);
```

From Ray Hayes (including the Where clause; I've reformatted slightly):

```
var query = listOfA.SelectMany(a => a.AList, (a, b) => b.C)
                   .Where(c => c.Length > 0);
```

Comment: @Jon, sorry I didn't see your comment. Now *you* can include Ray's answer ;). Thanks to both you and Ray.

Comment: I've been to this answer about 20 times so far. I don't know why I can't remember "selectmany" and always try "selectall", but it always happens. Lucky this is always just one google away!

Answer (score 17):

I too would have had a similar answer, my only modification was to add the where clause to avoid having empty strings (where C is empty):

```
listOfA.SelectMany( a => a.AList, (a, b) => b.C ).Where( c => c.Length > 0 );
```