# Convert List (Of List (Of Class)) To List(Of Class)

Tags: vb.net, linq, list

I have a class, which is stored in a list inside a dictionary, like this:-

```
Public Class MyClass
    Public something As Integer
    Public something_else As Double
End Class

Dim my_dictionary As Dictionary (Of Integer, List (Of MyClass))
```

I then need to extract some of these lists and convert them into a single list. I can extract the necessary lists like this:-

```
Dim list_of_lists As List (Of List (Of MyClass)) =
    From dict_item As KeyValuePair (Of Integer, List (Of MyClass) In my_dictionary
        Where dict_item.Key < some_value
        Select dict_item.Value).ToList
```

but cannot then convert these to

```
Dim list_of_items As List (Of MyClass) = ...er...
```

I've had a look at the questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649773/linq-list-of-lists-to-a-long-list) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145558/linq-list-of-lists-to-single-list) using `SelectMany` but I can't get anything using `SelectMany` to compile, and the C# usage (and explanations) are a little terse.

Using

```
(From one_list In list_of_lists
    Select one_list.FindAll(Function(x) True)).ToList
```

just creates another list of lists.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Look at the [`SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: He already mentions `SelectMany` in the question. So he has problems to implement it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim list_of_items As List (Of MyClass) = list_of_lists.SelectMany(Function(list) list).ToList()
```

In query syntax:

```
Dim items = From list In list_of_lists
            From item In list
            Select item
Dim list_of_items As List (Of MyClass) = items.ToList()
```