# How to select list of objects inside another list of objects

Tags: c#, linq, select, linq-to-objects

```
public class Account
{
    public List<Memo1> Memos { get; set; }
}

public class Memo1
{
    public string Memo { get; set; }
    public DateTime AddDate { get; set; }
    public string UserID { get; set; }
    public List<MemoRefferances1> MemoRefferances { get; set; }
}

public class MemoRefferances1
{
    public string RefferanceName { get; set; }
    public string RefferanceValue { get; set; }
}
```

I want to select values of RefferanceName and RefferanceValue in MemoRefferances1 class. Please Help me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linq: List of lists to a long list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649773/linq-list-of-lists-to-a-long-list)

Comment: What are the properties available in `MemoRefferances1` class. Only two which you mentioned in question or others as well, because `SelectMany` gives you entire object of `IEnumerable<MemoRefferances1>` class and if you need selective properties from that object then you need `Select()` as well

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`SelectMany`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netframework-4.8) to get all the `MemoRefferances1` in `Account.Memos`

```
var results = someAccount.Memos.SelectMany(x => MemoRefferances);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need [`SelectMany`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netframework-4.8):

> Projects each element of a sequence to an IEnumerable and flattens
>   the resulting sequences into one sequence.

```
var allMemoRefferances = account.Memos.SelectMany(x = x.MemoRefferances);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code,

```
Account dummy = GetAccouns(); //Assume GetAccounts fills account data
var result = dummy.Memos.SelectMany(x => x.MemoRefferances).ToList();
```