# How to get elements of a List of Lists in C# using linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I have `List<List < Address>>`  and I'm trying to retrieve elements in the child list from the parent list, below is what I have done but it is not what i'm trying to achieve

```
var getChildElement = ParentList
        .Select(x => x.Select(y => y)
                      .Where(z => z.Stud.Res.StudentId == 54));
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linq: List of lists to a long list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649773/linq-list-of-lists-to-a-long-list)

Comment: No it does not answer my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about [`SelectMany()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=net-6.0)

> Projects each element of a sequence to an IEnumerable and
> **flattens the resulting sequences into one sequence**.

```
var getChildElement = ParentList.SelectMany(x => x.Stud.Res.StudentId == 54);
```

---

As described in the documentation, [`SelectMany()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=net-6.0) flattens your `List<List<Address>>` into one sequence and our predicate filters out that sequence into the output.